# drupal theme_preprocess_node function not getting executed from template file

Tags: drupal, tabs, preprocessor

I am trying to print action "tabs" in my node.tpl.php file. I added the preprocess function as below-

function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {

$variables['page_tabs'] = menu_local_tabs();

}

Then trying to print in my tpl like below.

```
print $page_tabs;
```

But it is not getting executed at all. Infect the control is not going inside preprocess function when I am trying to exit like below-

```
   function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {

 echo "good bye";
 exit;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are replacing MYTHEME with the name of your theme right? If so double check that your theme is activated and set by default.

Comment: yes MYTHEME is replaced with my theme name. I doubled checked everything, cleared cache everything I did but not understanding why the control is not going inside.

Comment: I did not ask but your preprocess is in the template.php file? Or in a .module file not in the node.tpl.php?

Comment: Regardless of why your preprocess hook doesnt run (you cleared your cache?), you say you want to print the action tab on your node. Are you talking about the view/edit tabs on nodes? Because then it is controled by displaying or not $tabs in your page.tpl.php parent.

Comment: Yes I am trying to print  view/edit tabs on nodes. What I am missing

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your function seems wrong, it is a hook_preprocess_HOOK :
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7
So you should not have the second variable ($hook) in the function declaration, this might be why it is not called by the core.

To add or remove edit/view tabs on a node you need to edit the page template parent of your node and print or not the $tabs variable : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7

Comment: Hi Thanks for your replay. I removed the $hook variable as you suggested , and I am trying to add a message each time the hook is called like below_
 
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $variables['something']="Hello this is something ";
   drupal_set_message("Hello I am in my mytheme_preprocess_node");
}
 
But it is printing the messages sometime its printing and sometime not. Also I am not able to print $something at all in my node.tpl.php file.

Comment: It might be due to the cache if it appears to show randomly. Just clear it each time and/or disable it (configuration > development > performances). Else if nothing show in node.tpl.php the only explanation I see atm is that you have a template for a specific node type, like if your content is of type : custompage, you must have a template file named : node--custompage.tpl.php, so if you display a node of this type you will not run node.tpl.php.